# How to turn arrays into a dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have this array, and wish to turn it into a `DataFrame`, but get an error.

The array `k` looks like this:

```
In[10]: print(k)

Out[10]:
(array([        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  0.73820147,
        0.7381864 ,  0.73820208]), array([        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  0.74638753,
        0.74618251,  0.745983  ]))
```

Then I tried to:

```
In[11]: df=pd.DataFrame(k)

Out[11]:..

  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 354, in __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: That looks like a `tuple`, not an `np.ndarray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `tuple` to the DataFrame constructor.  You need to pass a list.

#### Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = (np.array([np.nan, 0.738202]),
        np.array([np.nan, 0.745983]))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The second constructor will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your `k` is a tuple containing your `numpy` arrays. Try

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(k))
```

instead. This makes a list from your tuple elements.